# Проверьте, пожалуйста, коротенький текст

Tags: орфография

Недавно проходил тест на грамотность на одном сайте - забраковали. Ошибки там, к сожалению, не разбирают. Поэтому буду признателен, если их укажет компетентный человек. Это уже ничего не изменит, но всё-же, очень интересно, что они там нашли. Собственно, текст:

> Удалённая работа для меня - это способ обрести больше свободы, как финансовой, так и свободы перемещения. Ведь не будучи финансово и территориально привязанным к одному месту, можно позволить себе, например, путешествовать и отдыхать, совмещая это с профессиональной деятельностью. Конечно, такой вид работы подходит не всем, так как он предъявляет определённые требования к самостоятельности и ответственности человека. Для одних это часто становится камнем преткновения. Для других же является вызовом, поводом вырасти над самим собой, научиться новому, и при определённой удачливости и упорстве, исполнить свои мечты.

Comment: Из текста не совсем понятно: а) переход к удалённой работе позволит вам преодолеть территориальную связанность в условиях существующих финансовых ограничений (вы будете при интересных вам путешествиях перемещаться без необходимости всякий раз возвращаться к месту работы) или б) вы одновременно рассчитываете на финансирование своих поездок (в интересах работы) со стороны работодателя (в процессе работы мир посмотреть). Иными словами, вы ищете просто "надомную" работу в сети, или работу, связанную с поездками за счёт работодателя?

Comment: @Alex_ander, Скорее всего, Сергей — не автор, он только знаки препинания ставил.

Comment: @М_Г  Это вряд ли, правописание почти в норме (ошибок мало), все вопросы к содержанию и стилю. Корректировать нужно и то и другое, а это не так просто.

Comment: Автор, действительно, Я. Для работодателя двусмысленности нет - он исключает возможность оплаты поездок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Для других же является вызовом, поводом вырасти над самим собой, научиться новому(1) и(2) при определённой удачливости и упорстве(3) исполнить свои мечты.***

(1) - запятая не нужна
(2,3) Либо две запятых (лучше) - либо ни одной. У вас - одна, что совсем плохо.

Это ошибки пунктуационные.

Остальное - или возможна альтернативная пунктуация, или ошибки скорее стилистические, которые нельзя признать абсолютными.

> > Ведь(1) не будучи финансово и территориально привязанным к одному
> >     месту, можно позволить себе, например, путешествовать и отдыхать,
> >     совмещая это с профессиональной деятельностью.
>
> Требуется запятая. Вводное слово ведь относится ко всему предложению.

Ох... не уверен. Ведь - это не вводное, а усилительная частица (а в других случаях - и вовсе союз), а тут и правила другие, да и к чему относится частица, сказать сложно. Я бы считал запятую факультативной - в зависимости от авторского акцента.

Comment: По поводу того, что *ведь* — усилительная частица или даже союз, я согласен с Вами и исправлю свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, что вопрос касается пунктуации. Если это так, то вот мой ответ (скорее мнение, так как на звание "компетентного человека" я не претендую).

**Удалённая работа для меня - это способ обрести больше свободы, как финансовой, так и свободы перемещения. Ведь(1) не будучи финансово и территориально привязанным к одному месту, можно позволить себе, например, путешествовать и отдыхать, совмещая это с профессиональной деятельностью. Конечно, такой вид работы подходит не всем, так как он предъявляет определённые требования к самостоятельности и ответственности человека. Для одних это часто становится камнем преткновения. Для других же является вызовом, поводом вырасти над самим собой, научиться новому(2), и(3) при определённой удачливости и упорстве, исполнить свои мечты.**

(1) По-моему требуется запятая. *Ведь* может быть союзом или усилительной частицей (см. [ВЕДЬ, союз и частица](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_263)). Так  или иначе, *ведь* не относится к  деепричастному обороту и должно быть отделено от него (имеет место обособление деепричастного оборота).

(2) Запятая не нужна. Однородные члены: вырасти, научиться и исполнить.

(3) Требуется запятая. Выделятся вставная конструкция "при определённой удачливости и упорстве". Для проверки: ее можно легко убрать из предложения.

Comment: 1) По поводу вырасти над самим собой.https://vk.com/page-45010268_52509317 В книге Прияткиной А.Ф.  Культура речи:  выражение «расти над собой» относится к просторечным сочетаниям.  2) Повод исполнить свои мечты - странное сочетание.3) Частица ВЕДЬ может относится к обороту, я бы не стала ставить запятую.

Comment: Вы меня подталкиваете к обсуждению стиля :). Ну что ж. Дополню. Под "это" подразумевается "предъявляет определённые требования к самостоятельности и ответственности человека". Но ведь не требования, а необходимость их  выполнять "часто становится камнем преткновения". Далее. Это (требования) не "является", а скорее **служит** поводом. Ну и, конечно, странно, что нужен повод, чтобы исполнить свои мечты. А причем мечты и  требования к самостоятельности и ответственности? Может, он мечтал стать  самостоятельным и ответственным?

Comment: Далее. Удалённая работа — от кого она удалена? От работодателя? Но тогда вы все равно к нему привазаны финансово.  А если вы ни к кому не привязаны, то от кого удалены?

Comment: Для удаленной работы есть определение, это термин https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Удалённая_работа  А финансово мы все сейчас привязаны только к банкам, куда нам переводят зарплату.

Comment: @Jasmin Из этого определения следует, что есть удаленная работа при постоянном работодателе и удаленная работа фрилансера. Последний действительно ни к кому не привязан. Но тогда надо говортить об удаленной работе **фрилансера**.

Comment: "финансово мы все сейчас привязаны только к банкам, куда нам переводят зарплату" >> Было бы что переводить. Это главное. Но по сути Вы правы: чтобы получить зарплату, можно обратиться к банку дистанционно. Какие тут преимущества у удаленной работы?